# How to get one package from Ubuntu distibution and manually install it without internet

Tags: networking, apt, server, package-management

My Ubuntu 21.10 server has no internet. Unfortunately, main package to detect route issues and other network problem missing in distribution. Therefore I can don't know what real route has my server because route command is absent.

However, now I can see my server from other peer bridge. I want to copy net-tools from other machine by scp, than manually install this most important package. But:

1. I mount Ubuntu LiveCD, add this source to /etc/apt/source.list - and receive answer "package not found"

[image]
[image]

1. How to locate package net-tools in http://archive.ubuntu.com/?
2. What part need to copy to target machine by scp?
3. How to start this package manually in target machine?
4. How to avoid GPG problem and other issue with trusted installed package?
5. I have similar problem with networking with various server in many years, in fact during all my carrier and in any Linux distribution. Why main package to detect network issues with tiny size developers don't included in any Linux distribution? What reason to delete so important package from LiveCD? I still don't understand this decision.

Comment: On my system, `apt policy net-tools` gives that it is installed from `http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages` . A bit of digging gives me that the actual link is `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` for my Ubuntu version and architecture (AMD64). You would need to download that file and install it with `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`.

Comment: `route` is a *deprecated* command, the normal command to view routing details is `ip route` & has been for some time.

Comment: @guiverc, thank you. Yes, this is answer to part 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find download links for the package here:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/net-tools

I guess you want the 64-bit version so click on "amd64" link, this will get you to the page where you have to choose the server you want to download from (it is recommended to choose the one that is closest to you).

Copy it to the target system and install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i net-tools_*.deb
```

Comment: @N0rbert the question was about installing a package on a system that has **no** connection to the Internet; using `apt-get` instead of `dpkg` in tht case does nott seem reasonable.

Comment: The methodology is wrong. This package is simple, it does not have dependencies.  Your great method will fail with any package with larger number of dependencies.

Comment: @N0rbert The whole question was about that particular package.

Comment: Then change  packagename.deb to "that particular package".

Answer (score 4):

For manual package downloading from an Ubuntu system:

`sudo apt install package_name --download-only`

For manual package downloading from another OS, use http://packages.ubuntu.com.

- Be to select the correct release of Ubuntu. (Example: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/net-tools). Wrong-release packages usually won't work.

After copying the package across to the offline system, use apt to install it:

`sudo apt install /path/to/package_name.deb`

For most offline folks, that was the easy part, and **this** is where it gets tricky: Apt might refuse to install the package due to missing dependencies. That means writing down those dependencies and doing another round of manually downloading and scp-ing packages across.

`sudo apt install /path/to/package1.deb /path/to/package2.deb /path/to/packageN.deb`

Sometimes several rounds of dependencies. I once had to do eight rounds of sneakernetting before I got all the dependencies.

After that time, I learned my lesson. Now I keep an online VM with an identical package set as the offline system (no data) and use the apt --download-only method, which captures all dependencies the first time.